# creating debian packages for Mozilla Products

Tags: packaging, debian, mozilla

I am trying to create a Debian Package for Boot-to-Gecko desktop client,
I have no prior experience in Debian packaging except the test cases mentioned in packagers guide and other places, I have created a Firefox .deb package successfully but the problem is as there are not such things such as how to make the Debian/rules file for boot-to-gecko available to me, probably I need to write to rules file based on the mozconfig which I created specifically for normal build of boot-to-gecko, now how to make that rules file? should I follow the rules file as it is for Firefox or any help ?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/fabricedesre/deb-b2g?

Comment: should have checked that before, my bad :( thanks for pointing me out :)